# style work in just one field when using keyUp password confirmation

Tags: jquery, html, css

The style I applied for works in just 1 field.

Please help

**My code :**

http://jsfiddle.net/ucg1fjvd/

**Jquery+Html :**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#password, #confirm_password').keyup(validate);

  function validate() {
    if ($('#password').val() == $('#confirm_password').val()) {
      //matching
      $('#password').css('border-color', 'blue');
      $('#confirm_password').css('border-color', 'blue');
    } else
      //not matching
      $('#password').css('border-color', 'red');
    $('#confirm_password').css('border-color', 'red');

  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="password" type="text" />
<br/>
<input id="confirm_password" type="text" />
<p id="validate-status"></p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to enclosed the else with `{}` to make sure both lines will be executed if the condition does not meet.

Like:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#password, #confirm_password').keyup(validate);

  function validate() {
    if ($('#password').val() == $('#confirm_password').val()) {
      $('#password').css('border-color', 'blue');
      $('#confirm_password').css('border-color', 'blue');
    } else { //Enclosed the else with {}
      $('#password').css('border-color', 'red');
      $('#confirm_password').css('border-color', 'red');
    }
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="password" type="text" />
<br/>
<input id="confirm_password" type="text" />
<p id="validate-status"></p>
```

---

Without `{}` Only, the first line will only be executed if the condition does meet. And the 2nd line will be executed all the time.

```
    } else 
      $('#password').css('border-color', 'red');          // <-- Else
    $('#confirm_password').css('border-color', 'red');    // <-- Not part of the else and will be executed everytime.
```